Matrix-Gaussian distributions
The point of this question is to ask for references on matrix-variate Gaussian distributions. But I will explain what I mean by a matrix-variate Gaussian with an example (the notion I have in mind is different from matrix normal distribution for example as defined on Wikipedia).
Suppose $x = \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\\ x_2\\\ x_3\\\ x_4\end{bmatrix}$ is distributed according to the four-dimensional real multivariate Gaussian distribution with mean $0$ and a (general positive definite) covariance matrix $\Sigma$. I am interested in the distribution of matrices $X = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 & x_2\\\ x_3 & x_4\end{bmatrix}$.
In the literature we know a lot about the case when $x_i$ are IID Gaussians. Another case that is very well-understood is when the covariance matrix decomposes as a tensor product $\Sigma = \Gamma_1 \otimes \Gamma_2$ where in this particular example $\Gamma_i$ are $2$-by-$2$ positive definite matrices. Indeed this is what people define as the matrix normal distribution. What if $\Sigma$ does not decompose as such? It seems that even in the $2$-by-$2$ case we know very little. But I am hoping that maybe I failed to find the relevant literature.
I said I want to know the matrix-variate Gaussians in this general sense. But let me be even more concrete about what type of things I want to know about this distribution.
Let us go back to the example at hand. Suppose we are interested in the expectation of an expression  $\sqrt{\|x\|_2^2 + 2|x_1x_4 - x_2x_3|}$ in terms of entries of $\Sigma$. Do we have technologies for calculating, estimating, or bounding such expectations?
Let me explain where this seemingly uninteresting expression is coming from. I am drawing from the multivariate Gaussian distribution but I am really interested in the spectral properties of the  matrix that is formed $X = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 & x_2\\\ x_3 & x_4\end{bmatrix}$. For example the expression $\sqrt{\|x\|_2^2 + 2|x_1x_4 - x_2x_3|}$ is just the sum of singular values of this matrix. So for this specific problem I am interested in the average of the Schatten $1$-norm (i.e., $\|X\|_1 = \mathrm{TR}(X^*X)$ which equals $\sqrt{\|X\|_2^2 + 2|\det(X)|}$ in the special case of $2$-by-$2$- matrices).

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but Chatterjee found asymptotic normality of $\operatorname{Re}(f(tr(\frac{1}{n}X^TX)))$, where $f$ is an entire function (for example polynomial) under pretty weak assumptions on the $(n^2 \times n^2)$ covariance matrix $\Sigma$. See the addendum to Proposition 4.6 in "Fluctuations of eigenvalues and second order Poincaré inequalities"

@Tardis this is a wonderful work and indeed the closest so far to what I have in mind. So thank you very much! I look at Proposition 4.6, but what I see is that entries of $X$ are taken to be independent. Indeed for such a distribution $X$, the distribution on $XX^*$ is the well-studied Wishart distribution. What if when entries of $X$ are correlated? So far as I am looking at the paper I cannot locate the point you mentioned about the weak assumption on the covariance.

If you look directly below the Proposition, there is a new sentence starting with "If we now change the setup and assume that the entries of X are jointly gaussian with mean 0 and nN ×nN covariance matrix ..." In the following bound the only way in which $\Sigma$ is used is the term $||\Sigma||$, so one only has to bound the largest eigenvalue of the covariance matrix of all entries.

@Tardis I am so thankful to you.
